# How can I force the user to enter an integer?

Tags: perl

I want to check that the input from the user is an integer number. I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
try {
    print "Enter int";
    $num=int(<>);
    print "okej";
}
catch (ValueError $e{
    print"not int";
}
```

Comment: Are you using the [TryCatch](https://metacpan.org/pod/TryCatch) module? Also, what do you mean by "doesn't work?" Please [edit] your question to show the exact error you're getting, if any, and the reason you think it isn't working.

Comment: not many perl builtins throw exceptions when they encounter something unexpected; instead, they give a warning (and you should always enable warnings so that you see them).  you may want to tell perl to promote warnings to exceptions with `use warnings 'FATAL' => 'all';`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Or, hardball tactics: `"If you terminate this program without entering an integer, all your files will be erased"`.

Comment: @Kaz Pffft.... "If you terminate this program without entering an integer, skynet will send a T800 back in time to murder your mother." Jon Connor didn't enter an integer. And we all know what happened to him.

Answer (score 2):

You really do not want to punish users for leading/trailing spaces (as too many web sites these days seem to be doing), but also avoid leading zeros. Also, make sure the output is flushed before asking for input:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $input;

until (defined $input) {
    local $| = 1;
    print 'Enter an integer: ';
    ($input) = (<STDIN> =~ /\A \s* (-? [1-9] [0-9]* ) \s* \z/x);
}

print "$input\n";
```

The [int](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#int) function does not check if something is an integer. Instead, it converts its argument to an integer. So, `int(1)` is `1`, `int(1.11)` is also `1`, and `int('a')` is `0` — with a warning if you enabled warnings.

See also:

- ["How do I determine whether a scalar is a number/whole/integer/float?" in perlfaq4](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfaq4#How-do-I-determine-whether-a-scalar-is-a-number-whole-integer-float). You should read the excellent documentation that comes with Perl.
- [perldoc -v '$|'](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH)

Comment: The non-greedy quantifiers don't appear to have any advantage over the standard ones in this case

Comment: Thanks so muchm,i will see that.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if input has only digits and nothing else...

```
use warnings;
use strict;

print "Enter integer: ";

my $input = <>;
chomp $input;

print "is int\n" if $input =~ /^[0-9]+$/;
```

Comment: for some value of "digits".  that will include all sorts of unicode "digit" characters.  with 5.14+, specify that you only mean ascii digits: `/^\d+$/a`. or explicitly say `/^[0-9]+$/`

Comment: Note that the `/a` modifier requires Perl 5 version 14 or better